# How to visualise a hyper sphere passing through 3D

Tags: geometry

Is this an okay way to visualise a hyper sphere passing 3D?

Effectively I was hoping to show x,y,z,w with w going to zero.

The number of spheres in project in 4D is simplified. The aspect means you can't really see the increase/decrease in sphere as it passes through 3D

When passing through 3D, does the 4D projections origin collapse (well, maybe expand) to the 3D origin like this?

[image]

To clarify, thanks to @AndrewDHwang, I have made a version of his 4D sphere passing through 3D & I would like to add the projection of a 4D sphere too.

[image]

In this thought, represent the projection (in red)

[image]

I hope the idea is clear.
The radius of the red 4D projections becomes a little confusing when w >> , I think the sphere's need scaling.
I've just realised the timing is off and effectively it skips a sphere.

Comment: FWIW, that is not how I'd visualize it, but I'm also not sure what is being shown in the intermediate stages; customarily (as in Abbott's _Flatland_) one describes the section $w = \text{const}$, a smaller sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Maybe there's a mistake on my understanding. As I understand a hyper sphere is made up of an original sphere and multiple spheres that extend into the 4th dimension, which collapse to the origin leaving only a 3D sphere at w=0. The principle of a sphere passing 2D would be a fluctuating circle and 3D -> 4D is a fluctuating sphere with the spheres extended into 4D expanding or collapsing to 0. Sorry hope this makes sense - if you've any posts or literature that would help in this area

Comment: @JairTaylor I read it was a method to create a hyper sphere, in the same way of folding square -> cube -> 4D cube ; I was thinking a dot -> circle - rotating around the dot -> sphere - rotating a circle around the dot ~ so 4D sphere rotate 3D spheres around an origin. (just explaining my thinking not claiming facts)

Comment: @JairTaylor I thought the main point of creating these 'hyper' 4D shapes was with a spatial 4th dimension and not using time?

Comment: @Teabelly You're talking about a hypersphere "passing through" a plane so you have to be talking about time, otherwise it is stationary.

Comment: I realized my previous comment wasn't quite right, though, let me try again.

Comment: Let's take imagine $d = t$ changing with time in the equation $$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 + (w-d)^2 = C$$ for a hypersphere, and then take $w=0$ to look at a 3D "slice".  You get $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 + (w-t)^2 = C$ which becomes $$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2  = C - t^2$$ which is a 3D sphere changing size.

Comment: @JairTaylor yes, there is a time component as it passes through the 3D plane but I would also like to think about / show the change in w itself, the 4D projection I think

Answer (score 2):

Here's a depiction where the unit three-sphere (the endless chain of descending spheres) moves through the hyperplane $z = 0$ ("our universe") by placing its center at $(0, 0, 0, w)$ and letting $w$ run from $1$ to $-1$. The blue sphere is the intersection of the unit three-sphere with $w = 0$.

In more detail, the Cartesian coordinates shown are $(x, y, 0, w)$, and the unit sphere shown in black is the intersection of the three-sphere with $z = 0$. The blue intersection, which properly lies in the hyperplane $w = 0$, is rotated into our universe by sending $(x, y, z, 0)$ to $(x, y, 0, z)$. This rotation fixes the equator of the blue sphere, which is a literal curve of intersection of two ordinary spheres in four-space.

[image: Cross sections of a three-sphere passing through three-space]

Comment: Nice, thanks! Really enjoy the animation. This is entirely a 3D perspective though, right? there is no 4D projection? For example if we pass a sphere through 2D the circle fluctuates similarly to your sphere (well, exactly the same) but if we wanted to do a 3D projection we could draw a 2D waist band like you have on your blue sphere, no? The hyper sphere is projection into 4D?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to show in my animation too, the fluctuation, but also in the 4D projection that at w=0 will have collapse and just be a 3D sphere, like pushing a cube down till z=0 and its just a square?

Comment: If I understand your first comment, no, this is a 4D picture. The black spheres are projections of the three-sphere in four-space, while the blue is the intersection of the three-sphere with our three-space. What's not accurately represented is the direction of motion of the three-sphere. Thinking of the depicted three-space as $(x,y,z,0)$, the three-sphere is moving perpendicularly to this space, so its motion cannot be shown accurately. The device here is to send the $z$- and $w$-axes to the same axis.

Comment: I'm confused, a 4 sphere projection is just a long external string of spheres? Why doesn't it obey the same principal of a set of points (4D: spheres) the same distance from each other? 
I understand this is a 4D picture but the black spheres are 4 spheres, no? Not projections? The blue sphere is in 3D? We want to project 4D to 3D? We cannot see 4D and I don't think you can project the same dimension on itself?

Comment: _Each_ black sphere represents "the" sphere in four-space. I made them into a stack only for visual continuity of the animation loop. :)

Comment: Yeah, It's a really nice way to visualise it! I would just like to visualise the 4D projection on the 3D sphere. In a similar way a 4D cube is projected inside?

Comment: Ah, I think I see: You're looking at pictures of a hypercube rendered as a cube-in-a-cube with corresponding vertices joined, and looking to see a similar picture with a sphere? <> If so, I think that's not possible. A projected sphere is two superimposed solid balls no matter how you project it. Careful inspection shows that's what the cube-in-a-cube is showing us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128222/discussion-between-teabelly-and-andrew-d-hwang).